# Update MSSQL db table with concatenated string extracted from xml attribute

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an mssql db table with 2 columns, ID and Value.

```
Id     Value (xml string)
1      <DAMP fullMedia="">
        <mediaItem>
           <Image id="1262" parentID="1244" level="4" creatorID="1" sortOrder="17" createDate="2014-01-28T10:47:06" updateDate="2014-01-29T11:15:27" nodeName="Juno 3D Side Terrasync" urlName="juno-3d-side-terrasync" path="-1,1236,1359,1244,1262" isDoc="" nodeType="1032" writerName="norgeodesi" writerID="1" version="6ac0d7fc-8482-4ddc-9d22-765c19586b01" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="Image">
  <umbracoFile>/media/3521/Juno_3D-Side_TerraSync.jpg</umbracoFile>
  <umbracoWidth>986</umbracoWidth>
  <umbracoHeight>1179</umbracoHeight>
  <umbracoBytes>202612</umbracoBytes>
  <umbracoExtension>jpg</umbracoExtension>
</Image>
  </mediaItem>
</DAMP>

2 <DAMP fullMedia="">
    <mediaItem>
      <Image id="1392" version="68d274be-5f13-45e9-a5c7-18e7ec221ca9" parentID="1244" level="4" writerID="1" nodeType="1032" template="0" sortOrder="60" createDate="2014-01-29T15:07:52" updateDate="2014-01-29T15:07:52" nodeName="Terrasync Update" urlName="terrasyncupdate" writerName="norgeodesi" nodeTypeAlias="Image" path="-1,1236,1359,1244,1392">
        <umbracoFile>/media/5396/TerraSync_update.jpg</umbracoFile>
        <umbracoWidth>240</umbracoWidth>
        <umbracoHeight>294</umbracoHeight>
        <umbracoBytes>25084</umbracoBytes>
        <umbracoExtension>jpg</umbracoExtension>
      </Image>
    </mediaItem>
  <mediaItem>
    <Image id="1391" version="4f3013cf-5485-469d-b403-c84b10901d9b" parentID="1244" level="4" writerID="1" nodeType="1032" template="0" sortOrder="59" createDate="2014-01-29T15:07:51" updateDate="2014-01-29T15:07:51" nodeName="Terrasync Screensnap Submeter" urlName="terrasyncscreensnapsubmeter" writerName="norgeodesi" nodeTypeAlias="Image" path="-1,1236,1359,1244,1391">
      <umbracoFile>/media/5395/TerraSync_screensnap_submeter.jpg</umbracoFile>
      <umbracoWidth>240</umbracoWidth>
      <umbracoHeight>320</umbracoHeight>
      <umbracoBytes>47988</umbracoBytes>
      <umbracoExtension>jpg</umbracoExtension>
    </Image>
  </mediaItem>
</DAMP>
```

I would like to write an update query to convert string in column Value to xml and then build a comma-seprated string from the xml containing Image Id's

I want that table updated to following:

```
Id     Value (string)
1      1262
2      1392, 1391
```

Thanks

Br

ALI

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want comma separated value of Image Id from your XML value (stored as `VARCHAR`) Try below query which uses [query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type):

```
CREATE TABLE  #temp (id int, value varchar(max))
insert into #temp(id,value) values

(1,      '<DAMP fullMedia="">
        <mediaItem>
           <Image id="1262" parentID="1244" level="4" creatorID="1" sortOrder="17" createDate="2014-01-28T10:47:06" updateDate="2014-01-29T11:15:27" nodeName="Juno 3D Side Terrasync" urlName="juno-3d-side-terrasync" path="-1,1236,1359,1244,1262" isDoc="" nodeType="1032" writerName="norgeodesi" writerID="1" version="6ac0d7fc-8482-4ddc-9d22-765c19586b01" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="Image">
  <umbracoFile>/media/3521/Juno_3D-Side_TerraSync.jpg</umbracoFile>
  <umbracoWidth>986</umbracoWidth>
  <umbracoHeight>1179</umbracoHeight>
  <umbracoBytes>202612</umbracoBytes>
  <umbracoExtension>jpg</umbracoExtension>
</Image>
  </mediaItem>
</DAMP>'),

(2, '<DAMP fullMedia="">
    <mediaItem>
      <Image id="1392" version="68d274be-5f13-45e9-a5c7-18e7ec221ca9" parentID="1244" level="4" writerID="1" nodeType="1032" template="0" sortOrder="60" createDate="2014-01-29T15:07:52" updateDate="2014-01-29T15:07:52" nodeName="Terrasync Update" urlName="terrasyncupdate" writerName="norgeodesi" nodeTypeAlias="Image" path="-1,1236,1359,1244,1392">
        <umbracoFile>/media/5396/TerraSync_update.jpg</umbracoFile>
        <umbracoWidth>240</umbracoWidth>
        <umbracoHeight>294</umbracoHeight>
        <umbracoBytes>25084</umbracoBytes>
        <umbracoExtension>jpg</umbracoExtension>
      </Image>
    </mediaItem>
  <mediaItem>
    <Image id="1391" version="4f3013cf-5485-469d-b403-c84b10901d9b" parentID="1244" level="4" writerID="1" nodeType="1032" template="0" sortOrder="59" createDate="2014-01-29T15:07:51" updateDate="2014-01-29T15:07:51" nodeName="Terrasync Screensnap Submeter" urlName="terrasyncscreensnapsubmeter" writerName="norgeodesi" nodeTypeAlias="Image" path="-1,1236,1359,1244,1391">
      <umbracoFile>/media/5395/TerraSync_screensnap_submeter.jpg</umbracoFile>
      <umbracoWidth>240</umbracoWidth>
      <umbracoHeight>320</umbracoHeight>
      <umbracoBytes>47988</umbracoBytes>
      <umbracoExtension>jpg</umbracoExtension>
    </Image>
  </mediaItem>
</DAMP>')

  SELECT Id ,
       REPLACE(
                  CAST(Value AS XML).query('data(DAMP/mediaItem/Image/@id)').value(
                                                                           '.' ,
                                                                           'varchar(100)'
                                                                       ) ,
                  ' ' ,
                  ', '
              ) AS Value
FROM  #temp;

drop table #temp
```

Result:

```
Id  Value
1   1262
2   1392, 1391
```

Comment: This query gives empty Value column.

Comment: @user1705714 works fine for me. I have added sample table with data and result as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you really want to `update` data in `Value` column but this solution does it. You can stop at any `step` (see below). This is working example.

```
declare @tbl table(id int, value varchar(max))
insert @tbl(id,value) values
--irrelevant data removed for brevity
(1,      '<DAMP fullMedia="">
        <mediaItem>
           <Image id="1262"></Image>
  </mediaItem>
</DAMP>'),

(2, '<DAMP fullMedia="">
    <mediaItem>
      <Image id="1392"></Image>
    </mediaItem>
  <mediaItem>
    <Image id="1391"></Image>
  </mediaItem>
</DAMP>')

;with step0 as (--convert **string** into **xml**
select id,cast([value] as xml) [value]
from @tbl
),
step1 as (--retrieve ids from xml
select id, t.v.value('@id','varchar(50)') imgId
from step0
cross apply [value].nodes('DAMP/mediaItem/Image') t(v)
)
--select * from step1
,step2 as (--combine rows into a single row
select id, stuff( (select ','+ imgid from step1 t where t.id=step1.id for xml path('')),1,1,'') newValue
from step1
group by id--to avoid duplicates
)
--select * from step2 --uncomment to stop here and comment rows below
update @tbl set [value]=x.newValue
from @tbl t inner join step2 x on t.id=x.id

select * from @tbl
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a hero!